# How to block touch functions in Kivy app temporarily?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to block the all the touch functions temporarily when some content is loading like, I have added an `MDSpinner` when its fetching some details from database and at that time, I don't want my users to type in the text fields or click the buttons on the screen. So, how can we do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp

from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

KV = """
<ModalViewSpinner>
    overlay_color: [0, 0, 0, 0.5]
    background_color: [0, 0, 0, 0]
    background: ''
    
    MDSpinner:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: dp(46), dp(46)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        active: root.active
        
Screen:
    MDRoundFlatButton:
        text: "Fetching details from database"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
        on_release: app.block_screen()
"""


class ModalViewSpinner(ModalView):
    active = BooleanProperty(False)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(on_open=lambda *args: self.change_spinner_state(True),
                  on_dismiss=lambda *args: self.change_spinner_state(False)
                  )

    def change_spinner_state(self, state: bool):
        self.active = state


class TestApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.spinner_view = None

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def block_screen(self):
        if not self.spinner_view:
            self.spinner_view = ModalViewSpinner()

        self.spinner_view.open()

        Clock.schedule_once(self.spinner_view.dismiss, 2.0)


TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But, can you please make the code a bit short please.

Comment: You can certainly do this, I just gave the most complete example for convenience

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much

Comment: Bro please help me bro, I have used firebase-admin, requests, cryptography modules in my Python Kivy app and it works fine on my pc but after converting to apk using buildozer, it closes immediately on my android device. So, please correct me bro please